# Given two bases of a vector space, prove this is also a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Working on a practice problem to prepare for a midterm this week. I'm a little stuck though.

Suppose $B_1 = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ and $B_2 = \{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n\}$ are 2 different bases for vector space $V$ over a field $F$. Prove there exists an $i$ such that $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{i-1}, w_1, v_{i+1}, \ldots v_n \}$ is also a basis for vector space $V$.

My first attempt replied on $w_1$ being a scalar multiple of one of the $v_i$, but I don't think this is necessarily true. Realizing that, here's my progress so far:

Since $B_1$ and $B_2$ are bases, they each contain a linearly independent set of vectors that span $V$. So, all $v \in V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $B_1$ and $B_2$. So for an arbitrary $v \in V$,
$$c_1 w_1 + c_2 w_2 + \ldots + c_n w_n = v$$
for some $c_1, \ldots, c_n \in F$.

Similarly,
$$k_1 v_1 + k_2 v_2 + \ldots + k_n v_n = v$$
for some $k_1, \ldots, k_n \in F$.

Setting these two equations equal and solving for $w_1$ yields
$$w_1 = \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_iv_i - \sum_{i=2}^{n} c_iw_i\right)}{c_1}.$$
(Not sure, if that's helpful in any way though)

How should I proceed?

Comment: Write $w_1$ as a linear combinations of $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ and note that there must be a nonzero coefficient.

Comment: The second basis is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring); you can instead prove that if $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis and $w\ne0$, there is $i$ such that $\{v_1,\dots,v_{i-1},w,v_{i+1},\dots,v_n\}$ is again a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $B_1= \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n \}$ and $B_2= \{w_1,w_2,...,w_n \}$ are two different basis of the vector space $V$. Now, as $B_1$ is a spanning set, we can write $w_1=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_nv_n$ not all of $a_i$ are zero. Suppose WLOG $a_i\neq 0$, then $v_i=\frac{w_1-a_1v_1-a_2v_2-...-a_{i-1}v_{i-1}-a_{i+1}v_{i+1}-...-a_{n}v_{n}}{a_i} 
=$ $a_i^{-1}w_1-a_1a_i^{-1}v_1-...-a_{i-1}a_i^{-1}v_{i-1}-a_{i+1}a_i^{-1}v_{i+1}-...-a_{n}a_i^{-1}v_{n}$.

So this means that any linear combinations of the $v_i$'s can be written as linear combinations of $S=\{v_1,....v_{i-1},w_1,v_{i+1},...,v_{n}\}$ because suppose that $v=b_1v_1+...+b_iv_i+...+b_nv_n$ then $v=b_1v_1+...+b_i*(a_i^{-1}w_1-a_1a_i^{-1}v_1-...-a_{i-1}a_i^{-1}v_{i-1}-a_{i+1}a_i^{-1}v_{i+1}-...-a_{n}a_i^{-1}v_{n})+...+b_nv_n$.

Distribute and group like terms together and then you can see that v is a linear combination of vectors in $S$.  Hence $span(S)= V$ and since $|S|=|B_1|$, $S$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: Why does the fact that $v_i$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $S$ imply that $span(S) = V$?

Comment: I just edited the answer, hope that helps